# My Eclipse java can not connect to R

Tags: eclipse, r

When I try, I get this following error:

```
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: Cannot connect: Connection refused: connect
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.<init>(RConnection.java:88)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.<init>(RConnection.java:60)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.<init>(RConnection.java:44)
    at com.google.java.JCR.main(JCR.java:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the extension of model uses from "r" to "rserve".

Visit http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Problem-with-rserve-extension-since-Java-update-td5002211.html